# Can't find EmberFire model data on Ember route. Error: Error while loading route: undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase, ember-router, emberfire

When trying to lookup a model using the EmberFire firebase adapter I get `undefined` and an error as a result: `Error while loading route: undefined`. I have also tried creating models but can't seem to persist them so maybe I have something incorrectly configured.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: new Firebase('https://emberfire-test.firebaseio.com')
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

jsBin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kuyujohi/14/edit?js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the emberFire not handing empty / non-existent collections. This has now been fixed in the emberFire repo.

Github issue:
https://github.com/firebase/emberFire/issues/39